# Getting `'utf-32-be' codec can't decode bytes in position 4-7: code point not in range(0x110000)` while consuming Kafka message in python

Tags: python-3.x, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am currently producing and consuming json kafka messages. I am able to produce the Kafka message.

```
producer.produce(topic=TOPIC, value=json_msg, on_delivery=delivery_report)

consume(TOPIC, GROUP_NAME, Msg, '')
```

But while consuming, I get the following error

`'utf-32-be' codec can't decode bytes in position 4-7: code point not in range(0x110000)`

My consumer and producer point to the correct schema, registry and servers. I am not sure how to debug this issue. I manually entered my Json message thinking copy pasting the json was an issue, but . Does anyone have any idea on what could be wrong?

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?